# PHP URL QUERY to array

Tags: php, url, preg-match-all

I have a problem with this:

```
<?php $url = 'aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff';
```

For something like this:

```
<?php $url = array('aa' => 'bb', 'cc' => 'dd', 'ee' => 'ff');
```

My code:

```
<?php

$url = 'aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff';
preg_match_all('[(\w+)=(\w+)]', $url, $matches);
var_export($matches);
```

Result:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'aa=bb', 1 => 'cc=dd', 2 => 'ee=ff', ), 1 => array ( 0 => 'aa', 1 => 'cc', 2 => 'ee', ), 2 => array ( 0 => 'bb', 1 => 'dd', 2 => 'ff', ), )
```

It's almost okay, I just want to get rid of this first key. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The key lesson here is that for common problems like this (breaking apart URL query strings) there is always an existing solution that has already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can get associative array by many different ways e.g with **regex**, using **explode** by `&` and so on.

But **If I were you**, I'll use `parse_str()`

```
<?php
$url = 'aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff';
parse_str($url, $query);
print_r($query);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array (
 [aa] => bb 
 [cc] => dd 
 [ee] => ff 
)
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/fjadK

Comment: Thanks @dont-angry-me, your method is definitely better! :)

Comment: @sopskirk You're welcome. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 2):

The parse_str() function parses a query string into variables.

```
$url = 'aa=bb&cc=dd&ee=ff';

parse_str($url, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```